# JQuery accordion menu using MySQL queries and PHP

Tags: jquery, mysql

I am trying to make an accordion menu using 2 MySQL queries (1 for the header and 1 for the contents) and PHP.  Below is my code PHP and JQuery code, I can't seem to figure out how to make the contents stay inside the headers.  Everything from the MySQL prints out in order.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PHP and MySQL

```
    <div id="left"> 
    <div class="menu">
    <?php
     $sqlseasons = "SELECT * FROM seasons"; 
    $resultseasons = mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlseasons); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultseasons)){ 
    $year_id = $row['year_id'];
    ?> 
    <h3><?php echo $row['seasonyear'] ?></h3>
     <?php 
    $sqlteam = "SELECT team.team_id, team.year_id, team.teamname 
    FROM team
     WHERE team.year_id = '$year_id'"; 
    $resultsteam = mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlteam); 
    while ($sqlrow = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsteam)){ 
    $teamid = $sqlrow['team_id']; 
    ?> 
    <p><a href="#" onclick="displaySeason('<?php echo $teamid ?>')" id="menu_teamname"><?php echo $sqlrow['teamname']; ?></a></p>
    <?php 
    } 
    mysqli_close(); } mysqli_close();?></div><button id="team-season">Add Team</button>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){245.      $('.menu').accordion();246.  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add more divs

Here

```
    <div id="left"> 
        <div class="menu">
        <?php
         $sqlseasons = "SELECT * FROM seasons"; 
        $resultseasons = mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlseasons); 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultseasons)){ 
        $year_id = $row['year_id'];
        ?> 
        <h3><?php echo $row['seasonyear'] ?></h3>
         <?php
```

Comment: Thank i really need some more divs here to add